# Crystal report connection not getting closed using SetDatabaseLogon

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

I am using crystal report (procedure bind) which is not releasing connection when I exit from report.
I am passing parameter to crystal as :

```
Dim InserSql = "exec USP_TEST parameter1,parameter2
ConnectDB() /* connecting to database */
DtAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(InserSql, Con)
DtAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
rpt.SetDataSource(DataTable)
rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("usrname", "password")
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt /* rpt is crystal report object */
Con.Close() /*closing connection */
rpt.Database.Dispose()
Con.Dispose()
```

Which closes connection in UI but not releasing connection of crystal report.
Please help.

Comment: How are you verifying the connection is closed?  Is this a winform or ASP.NET web application?

Comment: No it is windows application.I am identifying open connections from server connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logging on to the server with the report but setting the report's datasource to a datatable pulled with the dataadapter.  Once the datatable is populated and connection disposed you are no longer connected to the sql server as you are working with a dataset in memory.  Instead of setting logon credentials for the report clear the datasource connections and set the datasource to the datatable in memory.

```
Dim InserSql = "exec USP_TEST parameter1,parameter2" 
ConnectDB() /* connecting to database */ 
DtAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(InserSql, Con) 
DtAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
DtAdapter.Dispose() /* dispose data adapter after filling datatable */
Con.Close()
Con.Dispose() /* connection disposed */
rpt.DataSourceConnections.Clear() /* Clear existing login/datasource for report object */ 
rpt.SetDataSource(DataTable)     
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt /* rpt is crystal report object */ 
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport() /* rpt is refreshed with data from datatable and is not connected to database */
```